# How return only certain fields after insert data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have simple method that adds data to table:

```
$add = Recipient::create($input);
```

How I can get only certain fields after inserting?

I tried such:

```
return ["id" => $add->id];
```

Comment: You should be able to get those values without any issues, unless your mass assignment failed. Also, make sure you don't have those attributes hidden in the model.

Comment: You try and add  `dd($add);` after you're insert and see if you get a `Recipient` model.